# How do i add image in my gui window with tkinter and PIL

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

was trying to add an image in GUI window.

```
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
root.title("My Window")
root.iconbitmap('C:/Users/Win10/OneDrive/Desktop')

my_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("panigale.jpg"))
mylabel = Label(image= my_img)
mylabel.pack() 

button_exit = Button(root, text= "Exit", command= root.quit)
button_exit.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

error:
`Traceback (most recent call last): File "c:\Users\Win10\OneDrive\Desktop\PYTHON\kinter2.py", line 9, in <module> my_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("panigale.jpg")) AttributeError: type object 'Image' has no attribute 'open'`

PS- the image is in the same folder as my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're importing *everything* from `tkinter` after `PIL.Image`. *Everything* includes in this case [`tkinter.Image`](https://epydoc.sourceforge.net/stdlib/Tkinter.Image-class.html) which overshadows `PIL.Image`.

Importing everything with `*` is generally not recommended exactly for this reason. Prefer an alias:

```
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
...
```

Or import tkinter *before* `PIL.Image`:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
```